# Recover deleted files from Linode VPS with Ubuntu server

Tags: linux, ubuntu-server, vps

I have accidentally deleted files from my Ubuntu server which is hosted in Linode. I didn't enable backups for the server. Is there any way I can recover the deleted files? The server is using Ubuntu 12.04.

Comment: without the ability to boot from external media, and connect media for writing recovered files to, there's not much you can do in terms of data recovery on any OS. when you don't have physical access to the box, backups are your only hope.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer NO.....You'll have to remember to do backups in the future as part of your responsibilities.